# Consuming graphql query in Java

Tags: java, json, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-java-tools

I have Graphql query in this format :

```
query {
   priceData {
    customer 
    id
    title
    dob
  }
}
```

In java, we use this query in String format Like :

```
"{\"query\":\"query {\\r\\n   priceData {\\r\\n    customer \\r\\n    id\\r\\n    title\\r\\n    dob\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}"
```

Here we hardcoded this query. Is there any other where we generate this query dynamically?
Something like I create a POJO java class or Map type and later parse it to convert in GraphQL query string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if there is any library that can help you with this, but I don't think so (only for the creation of the schema but that is a concern for the server not for you as the client). What you can actually do is store the String in a file and read it and store it in memory when your Java application starts. This way it would be easier to read and simpler to change if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apollo graphql client. You'll have to store the schema and query in json files and use pojos and mappers to create the complete request dynamically.

Docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-java/